# Relationships are not loaded

Tags: mysql, asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have models Post and Tag. In my DB all relationships work good, when I use sql requests. But when I try get some post tag field is null and when I try get tag posts field is [].

I use MySQL DB and Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql NuGet

Post Model

```
namespace SuperBlog.Models
{
    public class Post
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 5)]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(5000, MinimumLength = 5)]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

        public int TagId { get; set; }
        public Tag Tag { get; set; } = null!;
    }
}
```

Tag Model

```
namespace SuperBlog.Models
{
    public class Tag
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 5)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public List<Post> Posts { get; set; } = new List<Post>();
    }
}
```

DbContext

```
namespace SuperBlog.Models
{
    public class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> opts) : base(opts)
        {
        }
        public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Tag>().HasMany(tag=>tag.Posts).WithOne(post=>post.Tag).HasForeignKey(post=>post.TagId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Post>().HasOne(post => post.Tag).WithMany(tag => tag.Posts).HasForeignKey(post => post.TagId);
        }
    }
}
```

Response when i getting posts

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "CS2",
    "description": "Cs2 is the best gmaes",
    "createdAt": "2023-09-23T14:03:08",
    "tagId": 1,
    "tag": null
  }
]
```

Response when i getting tags

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Games",
    "posts": []
  }
]
```

Comment: Off-topic, but EF generally uses `MaxLength`, not `StringLength`. I'm not aware of any EF Core providers that respect `StringLength`'s `minimumLength` property either.

Comment: Show us your actual Linq query - or just your controller action methods.

Comment: Try to use include in your LINQ query. 
Example:
_myDbContext.Posts.Include(x=>x.Tag)

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager

Comment: You probably only have to add `Include`, but there's no running code in the question.

Comment: To solve this problem you need to add Include to load relationships as others said. Is your problem solved ?  If not, could you please follow up to let me know?